# Input data from one form to another(external page)

Tags: forms, fill, out

I created a textfield on my index page and I need to input the value of this textfield in the Paypal web site. So when the user type £25 and click donate the Paypal website opens and the value inserted (25) will be posted in Donation Amount textfield of the Paypal page. So the user don't need to retype. I have the paypal buttom already working on my index page.

I know there must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like cross domain scripting issue (or CSRF). It states that you cannot access (for security reasons) in JavaScript entities from the domain other than your own web site. It's good to see the error messages you have encountered.

Also check this out [getting started with paypal exress](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure if I explained correctly. Please access my webpage http://youthlinxuk.org.uk and click on the donate buttom so a paypal page will open with the option to insert the amount. I would like to create a textfield where the button donate is currently placed and the amount will appear on the paypal. It's similar to this website: http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/home/ but they are not using paypal. Thanks

Comment: So, I've seen your form on "donate" button, I guees you could add an input field there with the name "amount" and the form should pass that field's value to the PayPal, also check this info from PayPal itself, for other options: [action values](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside)